# Oracle APEX - How to populate interactive grid using APEX collection

Tags: oracle-apex, interactive-grid

I am new to developing application using oracle apex. Please excuse me if this question seems very trivial in nature.

In a nutshell, I am trying to invoke a REST service programmatically to populate an interactive grid on oracle apex page. Here's what I already tried.

1. Created a page that has a button to invoke a process.
2. The process invokes a REST service to get all order lines belonging to a particular order. The sample response from the REST service is as below

```
    {
            "items": [{
                "HeaderId": 300100550016803,
                "FulfillLineId": 300100550016806,
                "SourceTransactionLineId": "1",
                "SourceTransactionLineNumber": "1",
                "OrderedQuantity": "10",
                "OrderedUOM": "Each",
                "RequestedFulfillmentOrg": "Vision Corporation"
            },{
                "HeaderId": 300100550016803,
                "FulfillLineId": 300100550016807,
                "SourceTransactionLineId": "2",
                "SourceTransactionLineNumber": "2",
                "OrderedQuantity": "15",
                "OrderedUOM": "Each",
                "RequestedFulfillmentOrg": "Seattle Manufacturing"
            }]
        }
```

3. If the rest service invocation was successful (http status code: 200), then I create the apex_collection as below in the same process. Also, I have set one of the page fields (P3_REFRESH_ORDER_LINES_GRID) to ‘Y'. On page load, the value for this attribute must be null.

```
if apex_web_service.g_status_code = 200 then --OK 
        dbms_output.put_line( 'Response : ' || l_data ); --if response was OK, print it
        apex_collection.create_or_truncate_collection( 'OrderLines' );
        apex_collection.add_member(
            p_collection_name => 'OrderLines',
            p_clob001 => l_data );
        
        :P3_REFRESH_ORDER_LINES_GRID := 'Y';

    end if;
```

4. I have then used the below SQL query to populate data into the interactive grid
   Set the region type to “Interactive Grid”
   Source: Local Database
   Type: SQL query

```
    SELECT ol.fulfill_line_id as FulfillLineId, ol.quantity as Quantity
    FROM APEX_collections c, 
    JSON_TABLE(
            c.clob001,  -- the following lines depend on your JSON structure
           '$.items[*]' 
            columns(
                fulfill_line_id number path '$.FulfillLineId',
                quantity number path '$.OrderedQuantity')
        ) ol
    WHERE c.collection_name = 'OrderLines';
```

5. Then, I have setup a dynamic action on the page item (Its a hidden text field)

```
- P3_REFRESH_ORDER_LINES_GRID
- Dynamic Action name : RefreshGrid
- When: Event Name: Change
- selection type: Item
- Item - P3_REFRESH_ORDER_LINES_GRID
- Client side condition - Type: Item is not null
- Item - P3_REFRESH_ORDER_LINES_GRID
- True condition: Action: Refresh, selection type: Region, Region: Order Lines (Name of the region containing the IG)
```

After I click on the button to invoke the rest service to fetch the order lines, the interactive grid does not display any data. Can you suggest where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

**Potential Issue(s)**

- **Step 1** You didn't really specify how your button works. If it is submitting the page, you *may* have problems with `P3_REFRESH_ORDER_LINES_GRID` field remaining null.

  - You could have Server-Side conditions preventing the invocation or on `Page-Load` you may be resetting `P3_REFRESH_ORDER_LINES_GRID` to null, and **Step 5** will NOT trigger.
- **Step 3**(Most Likely Issue) If you are not submitting the page, and you just have a Dynamic Action, executing Server-Side code: you may have forgotten to include `P3_REFRESH_ORDER_LINES_GRID` in the `Items to Return`.

  - Your `P3_REFRESH_ORDER_LINES_GRID` flag will remain null and **Step 5** will NOT trigger.

**To Debug**

1. You can try debugging your page here by checking **Session** under Developer Tools. I would make sure each step work and executes however I intend it to execute.
2. Also leverage [APEX_DEBUG](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.2/aeapi/APEX_DEBUG.html#GUID-8E80E46E-CCEF-4CCC-8D00-8EC3A5C36FDE) in my `PL/SQL`
3. Open your Browser's Developer Tools and look under `Console`. You should see `Dynamic Action Fired` lines there if **Step 5** is being triggered at all!

As you have not shared how your debugging went, and other observations after clicking the button, such as:

- Was the collection created?
- Is there data in the collection?
- What's the value of `P3_REFRESH_ORDER_LINES_GRID`

You should be able to see what the answers are for the above using Session.

Comment: Hi Norman - Thanks first of all for quickly responding to my question. The button submits the page data on click. Does the entire page reload and reset the value of P3_REFRESH_ORDER_LINES_GRID variable? How do I prevent this from happening ? Answers to other questions - 1) Was the collection created - Yes, validated using apex_debug in plsql. 2) Data exists in the collection. 3) Validated using apex_debug that P3_REFRESH_ORDER_LINES_GRID is reset to 'Y'. Can you suggest any links for using session for developer tools.

Comment: Well if you say P3_REFRESH_ORDER_LINES_GRID is set to Y after clicking then that means you're good. Data exists in the collection and all that needs to happen is for your DA to trigger after P3_REFRESH_ORDER_LINES_GRID is updated. Check if the DA was triggered or if the report is refreshing (visibly refreshing). Here's the link to viewing Session State

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/18.2/htmdb/viewing-session-state.html#GUID-F218A21D-C153-4BCB-8FE9-51C7FAA13637